# How to treat un-used input pins for the Rin/RS232 side on MAX3232?

Tags: digital-communications

I have yet to find a definitive answer or best practice on how to tie the un-used *input* (RXin) RS232 side on a [MAX3232E](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=max3232e&fileType=pdf) transceiver. I do know that, say for a TTL logic device for example a buffer/driver one would want to tie the un-used *inputs* to Gnd or VCC and let the un-used *outputs* float but with RS232 levels swinging above and below 0V to tie an un-used *input* on the RS232 side could serve no benefit or even perhaps force the device to consume more current/power.

To my question/s. What is the best practice to do with the un-used *input* pins on the RS232 side? In addition, what would the consequences be if I were to tie the un-used *input* pins on the RS232 side to Gnd?

[image]

Comment: the drivers are inverters. ... i would tie the inputs high, so that the outputs are low. ... just a personal preference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On those devices the RS232 inputs are already pulled to ground internally via a 5K resistor. As such you do not need to attach anything to the pins.

If you wish, you can tie the unused pin to ground. But remember, if you decide to add the handshake functionality later, the choice to short it to ground now can be a real pain to rework. For that reason, I would actually change your design to add a pull-down resistor to the unused T2N pin which can be removed later if need be.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> The transmitter inputs do not have pullup resistors.
>   Connect unused inputs to GND or VCC.

source: page 7 in [Maxim's datasheet for MAX3232](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3222-MAX3241.pdf)

Comment: "In addition, what would the consequences be if I were to tie the un-used input pins on the RS232 side to Gnd?" Again, from the datasheet, nothing - they already have a 5K resistor to ground.

Comment: Most RS232 receivers seem to work similarly to the MC1489.

Comment: @Jasen Egads. If that Jim Thompson beast is how most modern RS232 receivers work similarly to, I'd be a bit worried. True, the MC1488 was worse -- you could cook eggs on it easily. But cripes, the MC1489 was not in the least bit *green*! That thing got a bit toasty on its own right.

Comment: -1 Though this is true, it does not actually answer the question about the RS232 side input, and is actually misleading/wrong  in that regard.