# WiFi connectivity ceases on ESP32 when MAX3232 is powered on the same board

Tags: pcb-design, serial, esp32, wifi, pcb-layers

Since my issue could be lying anywhere, I will explain my design details a bit.

I have a 4-layer PCB. The stackup is Top-GND-PWR-Bottom.

```
Top: Poured GND polygon 
GND: Poured GND polygon (uninterrupted copper plane)
PWR: Only power traces
Bottom: Poured GND polygon
```

**This is the schematic of the RS-232 line driver/receiver**

[image]

**The layout on the PCB**

[image]

The [MAX3232](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max3232.pdf) is on the other side of the PCB (bottom layer), while the ESP32 is on the top layer.

The problem is that when the MAX3232 is not powered (by removing the trace to the power line, pin #16), the WiFi works on the ESP32. Once I power the MAX3232 the WiFi ceases to function, it doesn't connect. RS232 functionality works just fine, drawing 50 mA.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MAX3233 capacitor values are incorrect for 5V operation so it may fail to work properly.

The ESP32 is a 3.3V IC which might be damaged or at least go out of specs if you feed it a 5V digital IO from MAX3232. Maybe you did not intend to power it from 5V.

You are also leaving the unused MAX3232 pins floating, which may lead to damage or non-working circuit. The datasheet explicitly mentions the pins must not be left floating.

The MAX3232 can also cause large current spikes on power supply which can cause problems if there is insufficient supply bypassing.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head Justme. I don't know how I missed that capacitor requirements in the datasheet, sometimes you go blind :( Once I modified the pcb with some trace-cut and re-wiring to 3.3V, it has started to work as it should be. It seems, it didn't damage the ESP32 pins.

Comment: Besides, for the unused pins, I searched some resources here and there. Some say, there is internal pull-down. Some say, particularly, DIN should be pull-down or pull-up by an external resistor. [link1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/346010/how-to-treat-un-used-input-pins-for-the-rin-rs232-side-on-max3232) [link2](https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface-group/interface/f/interface-forum/703430/max3232-max3232-not-used-pin-configuration)

Comment: @Sener The questions are about different pins so that is why you get different answers. The datasheet is clear on this. Do not leave unused logic level inputs floating. This means the DIN1 pin in your case, maybe DIN2 if the ESP can even momentarily be a non-output. Best solution, just pull both up.

Comment: @Justme Peripheral Interest - A number of Semtech LORA SX12xx ICs are3V3 and NOT 5V tolerant. Many webpages have them being driven directly from eg ATMega328P / Arduinos running on 5V. There are body diodes to Vdd on all but one pin. I decided to see what was happening and why. First I ran a LORA module on 3V3 with 5V ATMega328. It worked OK. I monitored current drain for LORA (RA-02) and rest of board separately. LORA drain was lower than expected. || I then added 5V-3V3 level translators and bypassed them one SPI lib=ne at a time. ...

Comment: ... Result: Minor changes in I on most lines. BUT on 2 lines (SCK and ?) I_LORA fell to almopst zero and AVR current rose - power is being supplied via LORA body diodes and SPI lines ! :-) !!! || It still worked !!! . Motto: Drive them correctly ! :-)